# Retrieve Dropbox personal path from ~/.dropbox/info.json in Bash Script

Tags: json, bash, path, find, dropbox

In Dropbox since version 2.8, the path to your dropbox folder can be found in the file ~/.dropbox/info.json

In my case, I'm seeking my personal path, not the business path, which is not in the typical Dropbox location ~/Dropbox but on a separate volume.

My ~/.dropbox/info.json:

{"business": {"path": "/Users/ChristopherA/ReOrient Media", "host": 123456789}, "personal": {"path": "/Volumes/Cloud/Dropbox", "host": 123456789}}

I have tried using grep/awk, but can't quite reliably get just the path /Volumes/Cloud/Dropbox, as there may be only one first level entry (i.e. no business dropbox), and the order might different for other users (i.e. I can't always rely on last pa

Some people suggested using jsawk, but I wasn't able to figure out how to make it work, and I'd prefer no dependencies as this script will be used on multiple computers.

Ideas?

-- Christopher Allen

Comment: It's JSON. Why not use `jq`?

Answer (score 1):

A solution using a json-specific tool would be much more robust.

#### Using `sed`

Using just `sed`, and assuming that your json data is in a file called `json`, try:

```
$ sed -n 's/.*"personal":[^}]*"path": "\([^"]*\)",.*/\1\n/p' json
/Volumes/Cloud/Dropbox
```

Your sample json data was all on a single line.  If that is not the case in general, then it would be better to remove the newlines before passing it to `sed`:

```
$ tr '\n' ' ' <json | sed -n 's/.*"personal":[^}]*"path": "\([^"]*\)",.*/\1\n/p'
/Volumes/Cloud/Dropbox
```

#### Using `awk`

```
$ awk -F'"' -v RS='"personal"[^}]*path":' 'NR==2 {print $2}' json
/Volumes/Cloud/Dropbox
```

The above uses a regular expression for the record separator.  GNU `awk` supports this.  Others may or may not.

#### Mac OSX Version

From Christopher Allen, the following works on a Mac:

```
tr '\n' ' ' <json | sed -n 's/.*"personal":[^}]*"path": "([^"]*)",.*/\1/p
```

#### Using `bash`

```
#!/bin/bash
data=$(cat json)
data=${data#*\"personal\":}
data=${data#*path\":}
data=${data#*\"}
data=${data%%\"*}
echo "$data"
```

Comment: Thanks. My file appears to be one line, but the Dropbox example on their website is multiple, so I tried the 2nd sed example. However, I get some extra text (an 'n') as a result:

tr '\n' ' ' < ~/.dropbox/info.json | sed -n 's/.*"personal":[^}]*"path": "\([^"]*\)",.*/\1\n/p'

/Volumes/Cloud/Dropboxn

Comment: I mostly use a Mac, and its version awk in the default distribution doesn't seem to work with your example. I'd prefer not to have to update to the GNU version. Thanks!

Comment: tr '\n' ' ' < ~/.dropbox/info.json | sed -n 's/.*"personal":[^}]*"path": "\([^"]*\)",.*/\1/p'


<-- This works on a Mac. A bit worried about cross platform on Windows and Linux.

Comment: @ChristopherAllen Good work!  (I'm sorry: I do not have access to a Mac, so I can't test these things.)  I added your version to the answer.

Comment: I assume this last version worked on your plafform(s)? Which ones?

Comment: @ChristopherAllen The last version, the one from your comment and marked as working on a Mac, does not work for me on linux.  (It can be made to work if two back-slashes are addded to escape the parens.)  My understanding is that most Windows users would have GNU tools installed and consequently would be compatible with the linux version.

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas how to have a single shell script that will return the Dropbox personal path that will work on all platforms (Mac, Windows, and Linux)?

Comment: @ChristopherAllen I just added a `bash` version.  Since, as far as I know, `bash` does not suffer from a GNU/BSD split, it might be easier to make a compatible version.

Comment: I've confirmed that the bash-only version does work on the Mac (substituting in ~/.dropbox/info.json for json). Thanks!

Comment: @ChristopherAllen Excellent.